Spring Integration Mail IMAP
I am developing an Inbox listener for email@enterprise.ent using IMAP protocol with Spring Integration Mail. I am using XOAUTH2 to Autheticate and SSL.
The email is an outlook email, so as I want to use XOAUTH2 to be able to connect to the inbox, I have registered an application in Microsoft Entra, created a secret and given the corresponding Imap permissions to the application:

After that, via Powershell I have added email@enterprise.ent to be able to access to that emails inbox with a Jwt. The tutorial to configure the application I have followed is defined here.
Once I have granted the permissions to access to email@enterprise.ent I have defined the following IntegrationFlow.
I want to use an IdleAdapter in order to process the received messages as they enter in the inbox. As the token expires every hour, I have defined a javaMailAuthenticator to reauthenticate every hour (when AuthenticationException occurs).
I want to do the reconnection authomatically, so I have defined shouldReconnectAutomatically(true). As I want to process the messages and work with their body and attachments, I have defined .autoCloseFolder(false).
My integration flow is:
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow imapFlow(
    @Value("${debug.mode: true}") String debug,
    @Qualifier("outlookApiService") AccessTokenService accessTokenService,
    @Qualifier("complexHandler") MessageHandler handler
) {
return IntegrationFlows
        .from(Mail.imapIdleAdapter("imap://outlook.office365.com/INBOX")
            .javaMailProperties(p -> {
                p.put("mail.debug", debug); // Enable debugging. Shows idle protocol logs.
                p.put("mail.debug.auth", "true"); // Enable debugging. Shows idle protocol logs.
                p.put("mail.imap.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
                p.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
                p.put("mail.imap.closefoldersonstorefailure", "true");
                //p.put("mail.imap.timeout", "5000"); <- I have already played with timeouts without success setting 5000, 30000, 300000, etc.

            })
            .javaMailAuthenticator(
                new Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

                        var accesstoken = accessTokenService.getAccessToken(
                            "myTenantID",
                            new AccessTokenRequest(
                                "myClientId",
                                "https://outlook.office365.com/.default",
                                "mySecret",
                                "client_credentials"
                            )
                        ).getAccessToken();

                        logger.info("Authentication launched with token {}", accesstoken);
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("email@enterprise.ent", accesstoken);
                    }
                }
            )
            .shouldReconnectAutomatically(true)
            //Avoid closing folder when message fetching. This allows message reading without raising error.
            //The MessageHandler MUST close the folder.
            .autoCloseFolder(false)
            .shouldDeleteMessages(false) // Flag to delete messages of the email folder whe are listening to
            .autoStartup(true))
        .handle(handler)
        .get();
}

The authentication is going Ok:
2024-05-23 13:45:22.659  INFO 75598 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2024-05-23 13:45:23.472  INFO 75598 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2024-05-23 13:45:23.472  INFO 75598 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2024-05-23 13:45:23.472  INFO 75598 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
2024-05-23 13:45:23.472  INFO 75598 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.imap2Flow.channel#0' has 1 subscriber(s).
2024-05-23 13:45:23.472  INFO 75598 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started imap2Flow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0
2024-05-23 13:45:23.476  INFO 75598 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter        : started imap2Flow.mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter#0
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.6.2
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresized: false
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAP: peek
DEBUG IMAP: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
2024-05-23 13:45:23.521  INFO 75598 --- [  restartedMain] c.enterprise.project.Application   : Started Application in 8.583 seconds (JVM running for 9.101)
DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect returning false, host=outlook.office365.com, user=******, password=<null><- I dont understand this log.
2024-05-23 13:45:24.470  INFO 75598 --- [   scheduling-1] c.d.l.c.builder.IntegrationFlowBuilder   : Authentication launched with token *****
DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "outlook.office365.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [XXXXXXXX]
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=outlook.office365.com, user=email@enterprise.ent, password=<non-null>
A1 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 ***************
A1 OK AUTHENTICATE completed.

My message handler is based on something like this. After the messaging processing, I close the folder as I have defined .autoCloseFolder(false)
public abstract class CustomMessageHandler implements MessageHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomMessageHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
        this.logger.debug("Start processing message");
        try {
            processMessage(message);
        } catch(MessageProcessingException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            logger.error(ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            closeFolder(message);
        }
        this.logger.debug("End processing message");
    }

    public abstract void processMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessageProcessingException;


    private void closeFolder(Message<?> message) {
        Closeable closeableResource = StaticMessageHeaderAccessor.getCloseableResource(message);
        if(closeableResource != null) {
            try {
                closeableResource.close();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

And the implementation of the handler:
public class ComplexMessageHandler extends CustomMessageHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ComplexMessageHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void processMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessageProcessingException {
        logger.info("Start complex message processing");
        try {
            if(message.getPayload() instanceof javax.mail.Message) {

                javax.mail.Message emailMessage = (javax.mail.Message)message.getPayload();

                String subject = emailMessage.getSubject();
                String content = getTextFromMessage(emailMessage);

                logger.info("Received email with subject: " + subject);
                logger.info("Email content: " + content);
            }
        } catch(MessagingException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new MessageProcessingException("Error processing complex message");
        } finally {
            logger.info("End complex message processing");
        }
    }

    private String getTextFromMessage(javax.mail.Message message) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        Object content = message.getContent();
        if(content instanceof String) {
            return (String)content;
        }
        else if(content instanceof Multipart) {
            Multipart multipart = (Multipart)content;
            return getTextFromMultipart(multipart);
        }
        return "";
    }

    private String getTextFromMultipart(Multipart multipart) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
            Part part = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
            if(part.getContent() instanceof String) {<-If autoclose is true this retrieves an error
                text.append(part.getContent());
            }
            else if(part.getContent() instanceof Multipart) {
                text.append(getTextFromMultipart((Multipart)part.getContent()));
            }
        }
        return text.toString();
    }
}

Everything is going Ok and the process is processing the incoming mails correctly until the process hungs up and stops processing the incoming messages. The last IMAP debug logs I can see are:
    A2 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CLIENTACCESSRULES CLIENTNETWORKPRESENCELOCATION BACKENDAUTHENTICATE CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A2 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: XOAUTH2
A3 LIST "" INBOX
* LIST (\Marked \HasNoChildren) "/" INBOX
A3 OK LIST completed.
DEBUG IMAP: connection available -- size: 1
A4 SELECT INBOX
* 169 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* FLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)] Permanent flags
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 14] UIDVALIDITY value
* OK [UIDNEXT 620] The next unique identifier value
A4 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed.
A5 SEARCH NOT (ANSWERED) NOT (DELETED) NOT (SEEN) NOT (FLAGGED) ALL
* SEARCH
A5 OK SEARCH completed.
A6 IDLE
+ IDLE accepted, awaiting DONE command.
DEBUG IMAP: startIdle: set to IDLE
DEBUG IMAP: startIdle: return true

It doesn't return any exceptions or imap logs until I force the stop of the process. After stopping manually the process, the outcomming error launches:
javax.mail.FolderClosedException: * BYE JavaMail Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.handleIdle(IMAPFolder.java:3316) ~[javax.mail-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.idle(IMAPFolder.java:3159) ~[javax.mail-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.idle(IMAPFolder.java:3111) ~[javax.mail-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.waitForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:197) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:277) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:249) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]

2024-05-23 14:16:45.775  WARN 75598 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.i.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter        : Failed to execute IDLE task. Will attempt to resubmit in 10000 milliseconds.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure in 'idle' task. Will resubmit.
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:295) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:249) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.mail.FolderClosedException: * BYE JavaMail Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.handleIdle(IMAPFolder.java:3316) ~[javax.mail-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.idle(IMAPFolder.java:3159) ~[javax.mail-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.idle(IMAPFolder.java:3111) ~[javax.mail-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.waitForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:197) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:277) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted

DEBUG IMAP: IMAPStore cleanup, force false

To have more info about the error, I have enabled the SSL logs with:
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");
After the previous logs I can see this SSL logs:
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|19|scheduling-1|2024-05-23 12:16:45.768 UTC|SSLSocketImpl.java:1565|handling exception (
"throwable" : {
  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1364)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:126)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:271)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.ResponseInputStream.readResponse(ResponseInputStream.java:103)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Response.<init>(Response.java:133)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.<init>(IMAPResponse.java:60)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.readResponse(IMAPProtocol.java:412)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.readIdleResponse(IMAPProtocol.java:3212)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.handleIdle(IMAPFolder.java:3251)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.idle(IMAPFolder.java:3159)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.idle(IMAPFolder.java:3111)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.waitForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:197)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:277)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:249)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)}

)
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|19|scheduling-1|2024-05-23 12:16:45.768 UTC|TransportContext.java:341|Fatal (UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE): Connection reset (
"throwable" : {
  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1364)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:126)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:271)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.ResponseInputStream.readResponse(ResponseInputStream.java:103)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Response.<init>(Response.java:133)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.<init>(IMAPResponse.java:60)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.readResponse(IMAPProtocol.java:412)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.readIdleResponse(IMAPProtocol.java:3212)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.handleIdle(IMAPFolder.java:3251)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.idle(IMAPFolder.java:3159)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.idle(IMAPFolder.java:3111)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.waitForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:197)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:277)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:249)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)}

)
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|19|scheduling-1|2024-05-23 12:16:45.769 UTC|TransportContext.java:383|Fatal: failed to send fatal alert UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE (
"throwable" : {
  java.net.SocketException: Tubería rota (Write failed)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:81)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:380)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:292)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:287)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1591)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:989)
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:126)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:271)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.ResponseInputStream.readResponse(ResponseInputStream.java:103)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Response.<init>(Response.java:133)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.<init>(IMAPResponse.java:60)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.readResponse(IMAPProtocol.java:412)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.readIdleResponse(IMAPProtocol.java:3212)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.handleIdle(IMAPFolder.java:3251)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.idle(IMAPFolder.java:3159)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.idle(IMAPFolder.java:3111)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.waitForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:197)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:277)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:249)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)}

)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|19|scheduling-1|2024-05-23 12:16:45.770 UTC|SSLSocketImpl.java:1638|close the underlying socket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|19|scheduling-1|2024-05-23 12:16:45.770 UTC|SSLSocketImpl.java:1657|close the SSL connection (initiative)
DEBUG IMAP: IMAPStore cleanup done
2024-05-23 14:16:45.778  INFO 75598 --- [       Thread-5] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2024-05-23 14:16:45.806  INFO 75598 --- [       Thread-5] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-05-23 14:16:45.809  INFO 75598 --- [       Thread-5] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-05-23 14:16:45.812  INFO 75598 --- [       Thread-5] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 130 (interrupted by signal 2: SIGINT)

I cant figure out what's happening and why the process is freezing and staying as a zombie and how can I change my code to avoid it.
The tricky part is that I have launched the code at home and it works correctly less than an hour. If I launch it at my office, the code runs for hours without any problem (I left it 8 hours running), when the token is expired, it takes a new one and all emails that enter in email@enterprise.ent are perfectly processed.
Any idea of what's going on?
My pom dependencies are:
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
.........
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


Those dependencies are very old and out of support even under commercial license. So, please, look into upgrading your project to much newer version. Another suggestion is to not close that folder at all. In newer versions, if no new messages in the inbox, the channel adapter would reopen it on the next cycle.

I was using those dependencies because that code was inside a module of a java multimodule project with those dependencies. I tried not to close the folder at all as you said but an endless loop triggered trying to read the inbox every second.
I have taken that code in a new project updating the dependencies and it seems to work perfectly. It has been working for days without any problem, so it seems that the "bug" has totally dissapeared.
Thank you for your help =)
